# python read data from xml

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am using scrapy with python.

I am trying to get my xpath from xml file like this:

```
def getMasterContainers(self):
    containers=[]
    containersFromXML = self.doc.findall('MasterPage/Containers/xpath')
    for oneXpath in containersFromXML:
        containers.append(oneXpath.text)
    return containers
```

The xml file is:

```
<Containers>
  <xpath>'&apos;.//div[@id="results-list"]/div[@class="item paid-featured-item"]/div[@class="listing-item"]&apos;'</xpath>
</Containers>
```

When I print the result **on cmd** that I get this

```
container = ''.//div[@id="results-list"]/div[@class="item paid-featured-item"]/div[@class="listing-item"]''
```

#### My problem

When I try `sel.xpath(self.containers[0])` I got no result, but when I **write the xpath inside the code** like this
`sel.xpath('xpath written by hand')` I got the current data.

Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Are you certain your trouble is with this xpath? Have you confirmed that it's not failing earlier or later than this xpath? I'm not really sure how to run scrape with *scrapy* so I just ran the XML parsing manually, and running the following on the real document and a test document worked for me.

**first.xml** contains just the xpath and its parent structure:

```
<websiteInformation>
  <MasterPage>
    <Containers>
      <xpath>.//div[@id='results-list']/div[@class='item paid-featured-item']/div[@class='listing-item']</xpath>
    </Containers>
  </MasterPage>
</websiteInformation>
```

And parsing **first.xml**:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse(open('first.xml'))

containers = []
containersFromXML = doc.findall('MasterPage/Containers/xpath')
for oneXpath in containersFromXML:
    print oneXpath.text
    containers.append(oneXpath.text)
```

Outputs:

```
.//div[@id='results-list']/div[@class='item paid-featured-item']/div[@class='listing-item']
```

Which looks good.

**test.html** is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="results-list">
      <div class="item paid-featured-item">
        <div class="listing-item">Found A</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item paid-featured-item">
        <div class="listing-item">Found B</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And searching it with:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

sel = Selector(text=open('test.html').read())
for container in containers:
    print "Xpath: {}".format(container)
    result = sel.xpath(container)
    print "Container: {}".format(len(result))
    for elem in result:
      print elem
```

Outputs:

```
Xpath: .//div[@id='results-list']/div[@class='item paid-featured-item']/div[@class='listing-item']
Container: 2
<Selector xpath=".//div[@id='results-list']/div[@class='item paid-featured-item']/div[@class='listing-item']" data=u'<div class="listing-item">Found A</div>'>
<Selector xpath=".//div[@id='results-list']/div[@class='item paid-featured-item']/div[@class='listing-item']" data=u'<div class="listing-item">Found B</div>'>
```

Searching the result of the real URL gotten with `wget` outputs:

```
Xpath: .//div[@id='results-list']/div[@class='item paid-featured-item']/div[@class='listing-item']
Container: 25
<Selector xpath=".//div[@id='results-list']/div[@class='item paid-featured-item']/div[@class='listing-item']" data=u'<div class="listing-item">\n        \n    '>
# omitted 23
<Selector xpath=".//div[@id='results-list']/div[@class='item paid-featured-item']/div[@class='listing-item']" data=u'<div class="listing-item">\n        \n    '>
```

---

It looks like your xpath string has extra single-quotes (`'`) where they're not supposed to be. In the XML it looks like:

```
<xpath>'&apos;.//div[@id="results-list"]/div[@class="item paid-featured-item"]/div[@class="listing-item"]&apos;'</xpath>
```

Which when parsed will (as indicated when you printed it):

```
''.//div[@id="results-list"]/div[@class="item paid-featured-item"]/div[@class="listing-item"]''
```

You don't want the surrounding `'`s. This is what it should be:

```
.//div[@id="results-list"]/div[@class="item paid-featured-item"]/div[@class="listing-item"]
```

If you can edit the XML file containing your xpaths, remove the leading `'&apos;` and trailing `&apos;'` from each `<xpath>`. So:

```
<Containers>
  <xpath>'&apos;.//div[@id="results-list"]/div[@class="item paid-featured-item"]/div[@class="listing-item"]&apos;'</xpath>
</Containers>
```

Should become:

```
<Containers>
  <xpath>.//div[@id="results-list"]/div[@class="item paid-featured-item"]/div[@class="listing-item"]</xpath>
</Containers>
```

But if you can't edit the XML file for some reason, after you get the xpath text, strip it of surrounding `'`s. So:

```
containers.append(oneXpath.text)
```

Should become:

```
containers.append(oneXpath.text.strip("'"))
```

Comment: I tried really millions of times by removing the both quoats but still the same error, can i send you the whole code? it is just a small script

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Edit your question and put the whole code in there, and I'll look at it.

Comment: I have posted the whole code with the xml file. please i have to remove it after some time. i thank you for your help

Comment: I posted the code, please if you are not free to check it, tell me in order to delete it. appreciate your understanding. thanks

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli You're free to delete what you need, I copied it down

Comment: Can I go to sleep and we continue tomorrow? It is 4 AM my time :)

Comment: To be honest, the solution that works with me is making the name (in the xml) like this 'Date' instead of Date, thanks for your efforts with me +1

Comment: would you help me here in this question pelase http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803540/xpath-works-for-just-one-item-when-add-in-it