# xpath works for just one item when add // in it

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I have this html page

```
<page>
<div class="results-list">

    <div class="item paid-featured-item"></div>
    <div class="item paid-featured-item"></div>
    <div class="item paid-featured-item"></div>
    <div class="item paid-featured-item"></div>
    <div class="item paid-featured-item"></div>
    <div class="item paid-featured-item"></div>
    <div class="item paid-featured-item"></div>
    <div class="item paid-featured-item"></div>

</div>
</page>
```

and Inside each "item paid-featured-item", I have this:

```
<div class="item paid-featured-item">
    <div class="somethign">
        <div class="title">
            This is the title
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="anotherthing">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract the title using xpath.

#### what I have tried

```
Container = "//div[@class='results-list']"

for item in Container:
    title = "//div[@class='title']/text()"
```

I get 8 titles but each one is the title of the first item.

#### i am sure that is because i used //

what should I do please?

#### first

I don't want to use css selectors because it is not allowed in my work

#### second

I don't want to use `class="something"` because this div not always exist in my page.

#### third

i am using scrapy with python

#### fourth

appreciate your help

Comment: to be expected.. DOM `id` MUST be unique across the ENTIRE document. A query searching for an ID would never return anything EXCEPT the first one found, because it's not permitted to have duplicate ids.

Comment: in my page , there are 24 id with the same name which is `title`

Comment: so what else do you expect. IDs must be unique, so you've got **ONE** title element, and 23 illegal duplicates.

Comment: it is not about id, actually to be honest, i have the same problem even with `class`. my problem is that using `//` gives me always the first item.

Comment: you need to show your actual xpath/retrieval code. `//foo` will retrieve ALL foo items as a DOMNodeList, but it's up to you to actually process that list properly.

Comment: I edited the quetion, it is about `class` not `id` sorry, just typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your page looks like (`page.html`):

```
<page>
  <div id="results-list">
    <div class="item paid-featured-item">
      <div class="something">
        <div class="title">Title 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="anotherthing"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item paid-featured-item">
      <div class="something">
        <div class="title">Title 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="anotherthing"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item paid-featured-item">
      <div class="something">
        <div class="title">Title 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="anotherthing"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item paid-featured-item">
      <div class="something">
        <div class="title">Title 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="anotherthing"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</page>
```

To extract each title, you do:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
sel = Selector(text=open('page.html').read())

container = sel.xpath('//div[@id="results-list"]')
items = container.xpath('.//div[@class="item paid-featured-item"]')
for item in items:
    # *extracted* is a single-item list containing the title.
    extracted = item.xpath('.//div[@class="title"]/text()').extract()
    title = extracted[0]
    print title
```

This will output:

```
Title 1
Title 2
Title 3
Title 4
```

Comment: no my friend, what i wrote in the question is just a general case. I am asking about `//` gives me always the first item.

Comment: sorry for that, it was just typo

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I'm still working on it, I only got the first part

Comment: thanks for your highly appreciate efforts with me. my problem is that i am too get just the first item. i need to get each title in loops

Comment: because you already know my case, i can show you the code if you want. but not in public :)

Comment: what is the difference between yoru answer and my way pelase? they seem the same right?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Yours is pseudo code so it's open to interpretation, but it looks like you're iterating over `container` as `item` which is not its children. So `item` is the `container` element. Then, grabbing the title with `//div[@class='title']/text()` actually grabs every title. You want to use `.//` on a particular item to only grab the descendant title.